# Rails Heroku deployment error - push rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile, gemfile.lock

So I am trying to deploy my application on Heroku but haven't been able to due to this error. Have spent like 3 hours trying out different things. Gemfile and Gemfile.lock are same and I've even tried deleting the lock file and using bundle to generate a new one. Same error.

```html
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 562, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (525/525), done.
Writing objects: 100% (562/562), 353.47 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 562 (delta 286), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
remote:        *
remote:        Bundler Output: You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
remote:        your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
remote:        updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
remote:        
remote:        You have deleted from the Gemfile:
remote:        *
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to polite-worms-1500.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/polite-worms-1500.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/polite-worms-1500.git'
```

Here's the Gemfile:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.2.2"
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'thin'
gem "pg"
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'client_side_validations' , github:'DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations'
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'rails_admin'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
 
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

And the Gemfile.lock :

```html
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations.git
  revision: 023ddde13161dd614c8093f9a90305b57974776c
  specs:
    client_side_validations (4.2.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.1.2, < 5.0.0)
      rails (>= 4.0.0, < 4.3.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    actionview (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    activejob (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (5.2.1)
      execjs
      json
    aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.5.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.0.0.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.0)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (5.0.0)
      columnize (= 0.9.0)
    carrierwave (0.10.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      json (>= 1.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    cloudinary (1.1.0)
      aws_cf_signer
      rest-client
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    columnize (0.9.0)
    daemons (1.2.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.5.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.24)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.7)
    execjs (2.5.2)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    font-awesome-rails (4.3.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
    globalid (0.3.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    haml (4.0.6)
      tilt
    hashie (3.4.2)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.1)
    kaminari (0.16.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    loofah (2.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.6.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.7.0)
    multi_json (1.11.1)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    netrc (0.10.3)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    oauth (0.4.7)
    oauth2 (1.0.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.2.2)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-facebook (2.0.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-oauth (1.1.0)
      oauth
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-twitter (1.2.0)
      json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.1)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.18.2)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-pjax (0.8.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_admin (0.6.8)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.7)
      rails (~> 4.0)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
    railties (4.2.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    remotipart (1.2.1)
    responders (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5)
    rest-client (1.8.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.4.15)
    sass-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (1.3.6)
    sprockets (3.2.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    thin (1.6.3)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.1.3)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootstrap-sass
  byebug
  carrierwave
  client_side_validations!
  cloudinary
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  devise
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-twitter
  pg
  rails (= 4.2.1)
  rails_admin
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  thin
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.5
```

Comment: try doing `bundle install` before pushing to heroku

Comment: It seems that either you didn't `bundle install` after modifying your `Gemfile` or you don't have the correct files in your repository. Is `Gemfile.lock` in the `.gitignore`?

Comment: No I've done bundle install countless times now. Even updated my ruby version from 2.2.0 to 2.2.2. And bundle everytime.

Comment: Gemfile.lock isn't in .gitignore too

Comment: If you have specified to use ruby2.2.0 in Gemfile. then why is it using ruby2.0.0 in heroku? if you fix that then it would run correctly is what I believe.

Comment: How do I change that? I also noticed this but haven't found a way to

Comment: Should just be pulling it from your `Gemfile` as long as your latest `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are committed to your repository... which they are right?

Answer (score 1):

Got to application.js and delete //= require turbolinks
Then also comment out turoblinks in the gemfile and run bundle install and bundle update. Then I think you can reverse what I had just done and again run bundle install and bundle update. If not worst case scenario don't enable turbolinks and keep as is. Hope this works!

Best,
DH